# Registrar eventos en Laravel sin usar EventServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, eventos

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en laravel organizada en Módulos. Cada módulo tiene un `ServiceProvider` que en lugar de extender de `ServiceProvider` extienden de una clase propia que añade cierta funcionalidad.

El problema es que ahora necesito que mis módulos puedan atender a eventos y para ello deben extender de la clase proporcionada por Laravel `EventServiceProvider`.

¿Hay alguna forma de registrar un `EventSubscriber` sin heredar de `EventServiceProvider` como indica en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#event-subscribers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el *service provider* de cada modulo dentro del método **boot** puedes llamar al método:

```
\Event::subscribe(new UserEventSubscriber());
```

Pasandole como parámetro la instancia de un EventSubscriber que hayas creado en ese modulo, por ejemplo:

```
<?php

class UserEventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Handle user login events.
     */
    public function onUserLogin($event) {}

    /**
     * Handle user logout events.
     */
    public function onUserLogout($event) {}

    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     *
     * @param  Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     */
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber@onUserLogin'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber@onUserLogout'
        );
    }

}
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.html#method_subscribe